# Using maximum remote servers

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Im trying to distribute commands to 100 remote computers, but noticed that the commands are only being sent to 16 remote computers. My local machine has 16 cores. Why is parallel only using 16 remote computers instead of 100?

parallel --eta --sshloginfile list_of_100_remote_computers.txt < list_of_commands.txt

Comment: How many jobs are there in list_of_commands? How many cores do each remote server have?

Comment: @OleTange There are 500,000 jobs. 100 remote servers with 32 cores each. The local machine has 16 cores.

Comment: Post the output of 'head -n 1000 list_of_commands | parallel -D --eta --sshloginfile list_of_100_remote_computers.txt' to parallel@gnu.org

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you will need to specify the number of parallel jobs to be executed.

According to the [Parallel MAN](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html):

> --jobs N
>
> -j N
>
> --max-procs N
>
> -P N
>
> Number of jobslots. Run up to N jobs in parallel. 0 means as many as possible. Default is 100% which will run one job per CPU core.

And keep this in mind:

> When you start more than one job with the -j option, it is reasonable
> to assume that each job might not take exactly the same amount of time
> to complete. If you care about seeing the output in the order that
> file names were presented to Parallel (instead of when they
> completed), use the --keeporder option.

[Parallel Multicore at the Command Line with GNU Parallel](http://www.admin-magazine.com/HPC/Articles/GNU-Parallel-Multicore-at-the-Command-Line-with-GNU-Parallel), Admin Magazine

Comment: Thanks, im able to use all cores on the remote machines. That's not the problem. My problem is that parallel will not use all remote machines. I tried -j100 and it sent 100 jobs to 16 remote machines.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Did you tried --onall? According to the documentation - 'Run all the jobs on all computers given with --sshlogin'

Comment: --onall sent the same commands to the servers, 16 servers were running the same job. I need to divvy up the commands and send them uniquely out to all machines.

Answer (score 0):

If the remote machines are 32 cores then you run 16*32 jobs. By default GNU Parallel uses a file handle for STDOUT and STDERR in total 16*32*2 file handles = 1024 file handles.

If you have a default GNU/Linux system you will be hitting the 1024 file handle limit.

If `--ungroup` runs more jobs, then that is a clear indication that you have hit the file handle limit. Use `ulimit -n` to increase the limit.